# How to use ggez + imgui + wgpu?

Tags: rust, vulkan, imgui, wgpu-rs, ggez

In my game I need to render some in-game textures into UI (I'm using ggez 0.8.1 and imgui 0.8.0). As ggez 0.8.1 uses wgpu for rendering I need to use wgpu backend for imgui. So there's my question: how can I render imgui's `DrawData` inside ggez's `draw` function?

I've tried this code but it's not showing me UI (the other game things are working).

```
        let mut canvas = graphics::Canvas::from_frame(ctx, graphics::Color::BLACK);

        let ui = self.imgui.frame();
        
        imgui::Window::new("")
                .size([200.0, 100.0], imgui::Condition::Always)
                .position([0.0, 0.0], imgui::Condition::Always)
                .flags(imgui::WindowFlags::NO_RESIZE | imgui::WindowFlags::NO_COLLAPSE)
                .build(&ui, || {
                    ui.text(format!("tick id: {}", self.tick_id));
                });

        let draw_data = ui.render();

        unsafe {
            let encoder = ctx.gfx.commands().unwrap() as *mut CommandEncoder;

            let mut pass = (&mut *encoder).begin_render_pass(&wgpu::RenderPassDescriptor {
                label: Some("UI RenderPass"),
                color_attachments: &[Some(wgpu::RenderPassColorAttachment {
                    view: &ctx.gfx.frame().wgpu().1,
                    resolve_target: None,
                    ops: wgpu::Operations {
                        load: wgpu::LoadOp::Clear(wgpu::Color::GREEN),
                        store: true,
                    },
                })],
                depth_stencil_attachment: None,
            });

            let wgpu_ctx = ctx.gfx.wgpu();
            self.renderer
                .render(&draw_data, &wgpu_ctx.queue, &wgpu_ctx.device, &mut pass)
                .unwrap();
        };


        canvas.finish(ctx)?;
```